# VueJS v2 Guide. Using v-model on non-value property

Tags: vue.js

I am following along the VueJS guide, and I am looking at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model at the moment.

I tried to create a minimal example, but haven't been able to make it work.

What changes do I need to make so that the following two HTML statements are interchangeable as the VueJS guide suggests?:

```
<my-checkbox :checked="chicken" @change="val => { chicken = val }" value="A Bird"></my-checkbox>
```

and

```
<my-checkbox v-model="chicken" value="Chicken"></my-checkbox>
```

Here's the code I've got so far.

```js
// Components#CustomizingComponentVModel
Vue.component('myCheckbox', {
  model: { prop: 'checked', emit: 'change' },
  props: ['value'],
  methods: {
    uVal: function(checkStatus) {
      this.$emit('change', checkStatus);
    }
  },
  template: '<span>' + 
              '<input type="checkbox" @change="uVal($event.target.checked)">' +
              '<label>{{ value }}</label>' + 
            '</span>'
});

// Default app
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return { chicken: false };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>

<!-- 
     I am trying to create a minimal example of customizing v-model described at
     https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model
-->

<div id="app">
  <my-checkbox :checked="chicken" @change="val => { chicken = val }" value="A Bird"></my-checkbox>
  <!-- VueJS guide suggest that previous line is same as the next one: -->
  <!-- <my-checkbox v-model="chicken" value="Chicken"></my-checkbox> -->
  <!-- If I comment line 9 and uncomment line 11, what changes do I need to make in my code to make this work? Also, why are those changes needed? -->
  <p>Chicken: {{ chicken }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to emit the `input` event instead of the `change` event, as explained [in the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events):

> So for a component to work with v-model, it should (these can be configured in 2.2.0+):
>
> - accept a value prop
> - emit an input event with the new value

Alternatively, as hinted by the note in the parentheses, you can [reconfigure your model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) to use the `change` event:

```
model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'change',
}
```

---

Below is a working example using the default model, emitting the `input` event:

```js
Vue.component('myCheckbox', {
  props: ['value'],
  methods: {
    uVal: function(checkStatus) {
      this.$emit('input', checkStatus);
    }
  },
  template: '<span>' +
              '<input type="checkbox" @change="uVal($event.target.checked)">' +
              '<label>{{ value }}</label>' + 
            '</span>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    chicken: false,
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-checkbox v-model="chicken" value="Chicken"></my-checkbox>
  <p>Chicken: {{ chicken }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I just answered my own question. It was merely a case of typo. The model should've read:

```
model: { prop: 'checked', event: 'change' }
```

instead of

```
model: { prop: 'checked', emit: 'change' }
```